# Adding NSMutableDictionary to array through a loop causes an overwrite of the previous values

Tags: parse-platform, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I've got an array of objects from Parse.com that I'm trying to iterate through and pull out objectId's. My method is as follows:

```
-(void)buildActivityDictionary{
    arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayForDicts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    activityDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (PFObject *object in someArray){
        PFObject *fromUser = [object objectForKey:@"fromUser"];
        PFObject *toUser = [object objectForKey:@"toUser"];

        NSString *requestId = object.objectId;
        NSString *fromUserId = fromUser.objectId;
        NSString *toUserId = toUser.objectId;

        [activityDict setObject:requestId forKey:@"requestId"];
        [activityDict setObject:fromUserId forKey:@"fromUserId"];
        [activityDict setObject:toUserId forKey:@"toUserId"];
        [arrayForDicts addObject:activityDict];
        [arrayOfArrays addObject:arrayForDicts];
    }
    NSLog(@"\narrayFofArrays = %@", arrayOfArrays);
}
```

How do I achieve the desired result?  I've tried using `setValue`instead, but no dice. Also, when I try adding each array into a new array  `[arrayOfarrays addObject:arrayForDicts]`, I get the same result.  Here's the output from my log.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
arrayForDicts = (
    {
    fromUserId = lVlLN0ucKQ;
    requestId = SSrFp9pV1Y;
    toUserId = SG359LXCtA;
},
    {
    fromUserId = lVlLN0ucKQ;
    requestId = SSrFp9pV1Y;
    toUserId = SG359LXCtA;
},
    {
    fromUserId = lVlLN0ucKQ;
    requestId = SSrFp9pV1Y;
    toUserId = SG359LXCtA;
},
    {
    fromUserId = lVlLN0ucKQ;
    requestId = SSrFp9pV1Y;
    toUserId = SG359LXCtA;
}
```

)

**EDIT:**

```
someArray = (
    "<Activity:PMZO9LJ3os:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1579c520>\";\n    activityType = request;\n    fromUser = \"<PFUser:rJWrNWO15W>\";\n    toUser = \"<PFUser:SG359LXCtA>\";\n}",
    "<Activity:aV3zz4iVrE:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x157e6960>\";\n    activityType = request;\n    fromUser = \"<PFUser:SG359LXCtA>\";\n    toUser = \"<PFUser:SG359LXCtA>\";\n}",
    "<Activity:K7504CAYnl:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x157e7810>\";\n    activityType = request;\n    fromUser = \"<PFUser:xMbXLMIv99>\";\n    toUser = \"<PFUser:SG359LXCtA>\";\n}",
    "<Activity:SSrFp9pV1Y:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x157e72c0>\";\n    activityType = request;\n    fromUser = \"<PFUser:lVlLN0ucKQ>\";\n    toUser = \"<PFUser:SG359LXCtA>\";\n}"
)
```

Comment: NSLog the someArray.What is the output of this ?

Comment: Hey Nimisha. I've updated my original question to show the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code :

```
-(void)buildActivityDictionary{

arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrayForDicts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (PFObject *object in someArray){

    NSMutableDictionary *activityDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    PFObject *fromUser = [object objectForKey:@"fromUser"];
    PFObject *toUser = [object objectForKey:@"toUser"];

    NSString *requestId = object.objectId;
    NSString *fromUserId = fromUser.objectId;
    NSString *toUserId = toUser.objectId;

    [activityDict setObject:requestId forKey:@"requestId"];
    [activityDict setObject:fromUserId forKey:@"fromUserId"];
    [activityDict setObject:toUserId forKey:@"toUserId"];
    [arrayForDicts addObject:activityDict];
   // [arrayOfArrays addObject:arrayForDicts];
    }
     NSLog(@"arrayForDicts = %@", arrayForDicts);
}
```

Create a dictionary inside the loop. In your code you create the dictionary outside the loop.Every time the loop is iterate it overwrite its old value.And because of this reason your array of dictionary only contains the last object.

One more thing,instead of these 2 statements

```
    PFObject *fromUser = [object objectForKey:@"fromUser"];
    PFObject *toUser = [object objectForKey:@"toUser"];
```

you can also write:

```
    PFUser *fromUser = [object objectForKey:@"fromUser"];
    PFUser *toUser = [object objectForKey:@"toUser"];
```

Becase "fromUser" and "toUser" is of type PFUser as shown in your someArray Log.

Comment: Aha! Boy, do I feel silly. Thanks so much for clearing that up for me! Pretty much ruined my night last night. And thanks for the PFUser pointers, no pun intended.